# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function fql_query() on a non-object in /home/elankeer/public_html/hiddenfriend/index.php on line 292

Tags: facebook

I am using facebook.php which is downloaded from http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

Below code

```
$fql = 'SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1='.$user.') AND has_added_app = 1';
$_friends = $facebook->api_client->fql_query($fql);
```

Throw error as below

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member
>   function fql_query() on a non-object
>   in
>   /home/elankeer/public_html/friend/index.php
>   on line 292

please help me!!

Comment: `api_client` is not an object for reasons outside the code you quote.

Answer (score 4):

In new facebook api sdk we need to do the following code

`$_friends = $facebook->api(array(
      'method' => 'fql.query',
      'query' => 'SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1='.$uid.') AND has_added_app = 1',
    ));`

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=223391